# How to set frame UITableviewCell image size?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use a small image size, such are 26*27, 15*28,... but the image is stretched and how to avoid and to set all image alignment are center.

Comment: is my code not working for u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following method for to specify the height and width of image

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return `NewImage`, with a specific size that you specify

Comment: wt u  mean ?? i dnot understand

Comment: all cell image align at start frame bounds but i want center

Comment: put this image in UIIMageView and UIIMageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

Comment: There's no way to center vertically as the method for this has been deprecated by apple in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your image to center of image using `UIViewContentModeCenter`

Using code

```
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

using Nib

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think u want :

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Comment: it also stretched image size any way to set frame

Comment: cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cat%d.png",indexPath.row]];
            [inImView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

Comment: do: `[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];` instead of `[inImView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];`

Comment: all images are not shown correctly some images stretched and how to set all imageview vertical align